# selecting unique values from a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which contains the following type of information:

```
    Date            product 
2011-12-12           azd
2011-12-12           yxm
2011-12-10           sdx
2011-12-10           ssdd
```

Here is an example of a script I use to get data from this table:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buy ORDER BY Date");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

 echo "<li><a href='http://www.website/". $row['Date'].".html'>buy ". date("j, M Y", strtotime($row["Date"]))."</a></li>";

    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This script displays every date from the table, e.g.

```
12.dec 2011
12.dec.2011
10.dec.2011
10.dec.2011
```

I would like to only display unique dates, e.g.

```
12.dec.2011
10.dec.2011
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL How to Return Unique/Distinct Results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663181/mysql-how-to-return-unique-distinct-results)

Comment: Not really sure the proper etiquette for this, but I have a need for something that is similar to this.  I have a list of the values like those above  displayed as  a list of all the dates.  I want to add some extra space between the end of one date sequence and the start of another.  Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Use the [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) operator in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) AS Date FROM buy ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Comment: The unfortunate problem of `DISTINCT` is that it only returns that one field... so if you want the whole record, the DISTINCT is worthless (unless it is an id field, and you can do a second query where id IN that list). Good news, though, if you have multiple duplicate results as a result of a JOIN you can do a GROUP BY and get the full results filtered.

Comment: That is not correct Chadwick Meyer ! You can chose multiple fields, but you have to group them. You can make it like this: SELECT DISTINCT(name) AS yourName, id AS yourId FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY name . You'll be surprised !

Answer (score 44):

use

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM buy ORDER BY Date
```

so MySQL removes duplicates

BTW: using explicit column names in `SELECT` uses less resources in PHP when you're getting a large result from MySQL

Comment: can you explain "using explicit column names" ? which way is less resource taking and which one is high? with example a bit please?

Comment: Common use case is to "stream" data from database into multidimensional array in PHP; so your PHP process simply wastes memory with data you might not need. For only some datasets this is negligible, but when handling thousands of rows, this could make a difference.

Comment: @NabeelKhan instead of using SELECT * ... use SELECT column 1, column 2... Unless you really do need all columns.

Comment: @LPChip using tablename.columnname is beneficial over only columnname?

Comment: @NabeelKhan you only need tablename.columnname when you join tables.

Comment: @LPChip i understand, my question is that if we do that in normal queries, is it any faster? or it gives error?

Answer (score 26):

Use this query to get values

```
SELECT * FROM `buy` group by date order by date DESC
```

Comment: I found that this was not helpful. Say you have 5 items, all with the same `date` but different `description`. Using the above command _will_ show distinct `date`s, but only the `description` of the first item found.

Comment: @onebree - in that case, you can do `GROUP BY date,description`.

Answer (score 19):

The rest are almost correct, except they should order by Date DESC

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) AS Date FROM buy ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Answer (score 5):

`DISTINCT` is always a right choice to get unique values. Also you can do it alternatively without using it. That's `GROUP BY`. Which has simply add at the end of the query and followed by the column name.

```
SELECT * FROM buy GROUP BY date,description
```

Answer (score 4):

Another `DISTINCT` answer, but with multiple values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `field1`, `field2`, `field3` FROM `some_table`  WHERE `some_field` > 5000 ORDER BY `some_field`
```

Comment: Perhaps explain how this technique (which makes no attempt to relate to the OP's question) behaves so that researchers can decide whether it will work as they need it to.

Comment: @mickmackusa - As stated on the description, there's nothing special about this answer, it just demonstrates how to use multiple `DISTINCT` fields on a `SELECT` query.

Comment: So does it ensure that the column immediately following the keyword is unique and the remaining columns may or may not be unique? Or does it ensure that the combination of all columns are unique in the result set?This is what researchers who don't understand the syntax might ask themselves. This is why you should explain your answer more generously. You could choose to argue with me that your post is "good enough", but that will be a futile waste of time. My honest opinion is that this answer is probably better transferred to a question that is asking for a resultset with more than one column.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've no time to reply. Down vote if you may, which is normally the way to disagree with an answer. Good luck.

Comment: I will only DV wrong answers and answers that misinform because they "do harm".  This answer is simply not informing.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this in case you also want to output products details per date as JSON and the `MySQL` version does not support `JSON` functions.

```
SELECT `date`,
CONCAT('{',GROUP_CONCAT('{\"id\": \"',`product_id`,'\",\"name\": \"',`product_name`,'\"}'),'}') as `productsJSON`
FROM `buy` group by `date` 
order by `date` DESC

 product_id product_name     date  
|    1     |     azd    | 2011-12-12 |
|    2     |     xyz    | 2011-12-12 |
|    3     |     ase    | 2011-12-11 |
|    4     |     azwed  | 2011-12-11 |
|    5     |     wed    | 2011-12-10 |
|    6     |     cvg    | 2011-12-10 |
|    7     |     cvig   | 2011-12-09 |

RESULT
       date                                productsJSON
2011-12-12T00:00:00Z    {{"id": "1","name": "azd"},{"id": "2","name": "xyz"}}
2011-12-11T00:00:00Z    {{"id": "3","name": "ase"},{"id": "4","name": "azwed"}}
2011-12-10T00:00:00Z    {{"id": "5","name": "wed"},{"id": "6","name": "cvg"}}
2011-12-09T00:00:00Z    {{"id": "7","name": "cvig"}}
```

Try it out in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86c400/3)

If you are using a `MySQL` version that supports `JSON` functions then the above query could be re-written:

```
SELECT `date`,JSON_OBJECTAGG(CONCAT('product-',`product_id`),JSON_OBJECT('id', `product_id`, 'name', `product_name`)) as `productsJSON`
FROM `buy` group by `date`
order by `date` DESC;
```

Try both in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7DZby8HCaEgGCku1rxjDS5/0)

Comment: Yikes!  Please do not encourage manually construct json strings via aggregate and string function in sql -- it is an inappropriate tool that is vulnerable to breakage depending on the data.  Even if it works in this case, there will be a cleaner and easier to maintain way to do this outside of sql.

Comment: @mickmackusa if you are using a version that does not support natively `JSON` functions this is something that you could do. In addition the problem of breaking data is solvable. In the above case the field that needs attention is `product_name`. Thanks for your comment. Long time i heard **Yikes**.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need.

In this case I suggest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Date) AS Date FROM buy ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

because there are few fields and the execution time of `DISTINCT` is lower than the execution of `GROUP BY`.

In other cases, for example where there are many fields, I prefer:

```
SELECT * FROM buy GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific keyword for the achieving the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( Date ) AS Date 
FROM   buy 
ORDER  BY Date DESC;
```