# in array skip the values from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: Select only unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571902/mysql-select-only-unique-values-from-a-column)

iam getting values from mysql table category and column parent.
Parent contain values like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4

I want to skip the values if they are repeating. So i want the output as 1,2,3,4

Please help me..my code is not woking.

```
$new_cat1 = $cat1;
    foreach($cat1 as $category){
        $query="SELECT parent FROM categories where id='$category'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);  
        $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        array_push($new_cat1,$line['parent']);
        if (in_array("1", $new_cat1)) {
        continue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

add `DISTINCT` in your query so it will select only the unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM categories where id='$category'
```

Comment: how can push that particular distinct parent into array

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a parallel way of doing this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM categories where id='$category' group by parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Change query to that : `SELECT parent FROM categories where id='$category' GROUP BY parent`

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT parent FROM categories where id='$category'
group by parent
```