# find same table rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

in buy table . when customer buy same book 1 row add to table . so when see buy list in buy page its like this :

```
buy1 price1 downloadlink1
buy1 price1 downloadlink1
buy1 price1 downloadlink1
buy2 price2 downloadlink2
buy2 price2 downloadlink2
buy2 price2 downloadlink2
```

but i want in same row price and downloadlink delete and only first row show this value 
like this :

```
buy1 price1 downloadlink1
buy1 
buy1 
buy2 price2 downloadlink2
buy2 
buy2
```

how can i use sql query???

Comment: please post what kind of tables you have, is it possible for a user to buy the same book over and over?

Comment: yes each user can buy same book because each book work only in one pc

Comment: I don't understand what you are exactly trying to do? why you want two blanks rows for buy1? blank rows don't make sense for data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if it would be MS SQL server I could suggest using `row_number over()`
But in your situation I can suggest try this (I suppose you have some id in your table)

```
select
    A.sub,
    case when A.frst = 1 then A.user else null end as user,
    case when A.frst = 1 then A.versionid else null end as versionid,
    case when A.frst = 1 then A.hard else null end as hard,
    case when A.frst = 1 then A.active else null end as active,
    case when A.frst = 1 then A.res else null end as res
from
(
    select
        *,
        case
            when exists
            (
                select * 
                from buy as tt
                where
                    tt.sub = t.sub and tt.res = t.res and
                    tt.user = t.user and tt.versionid = t.versionid and
                    tt.hard = t.hard and tt.active = t.active and
                    tt.id < t.id
            ) then 0
            else 1
        end as frst
    from buy as t
) as A
order by A.sub, A.frst desc
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/359fe/5)

Comment: i use mysql server . this code works but i dont know how change this code to mysql .

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM buy WHERE user='$userf' AND active='1' ORDER BY sub") or die(mysql_error())// and i have 'id' auto in table . it means i have to compare value(i) with value(i-1)?

Comment: if you post you table schema I could post you your real query

Comment: table buy (id,user,versionid,sub,hard,active,res) // and in the first row i want show all thing but in second or more row i want only show sub value in page .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20228/discussion-between-behzad-n-and-roman-pekar)

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` in sql query while doing download link

Comment: how can i use this? can you give me a sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571902/mysql-select-only-unique-values-from-a-column

Comment: i use this//mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `buy` WHERE `user`='$userf' AND `active`='1' ORDER BY `sub`") or die(mysql_error());//but not work

Comment: distinct will give ONE row (total two one for buy1 and another for buy2), however OP don't need two rows. OP want all 6 rows back...

Answer (score 0):

> Add row to the table if that particular item is not added by that user
>   into the table
>
> if that item already exist (check using item id and userid) update the
>   table