# how can i stop duplicate values from being shown?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I Have been trying to figure this out for 2 days with no real success

This is the code I have

```
$splash_list = '';

$splash_array = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE receiver='$username' OR sender='$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        if($username == $row['sender']){
                $otuser = array_push($splash_array, $row['receiver']);
                $this_user = $row['sender'];
        } else {
                $otuser = array_push($splash_array, $row['sender']);
                $this_user = $row['receiver'];
        }

 }
foreach($splash_array as $otuser){
        $splash_list .= '<div>'.$otuser.'<br></div>';
}
```

The output is 
  otuser1
  otuser1
  otuser1
  otuser2
  otuser2

If any one can give me a pointer on how i'd go about
only outputting each value once like so 
otuser1
otuser2

It'd be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: why not change the query instead to `distinct` rather than processing unique values in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8571902/1740715

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you could do `SELECT DISTINCT ...` ([DISTINCT optimization docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html))

But there's some other serious concerns with your code...

1. `SELECT *` is [evil](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-%2a-is-evil)
2. `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
3. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

---

Look into using PHP's [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for more help.

Your resulting code will look something like

```
$query = $db->prepare("
  SELECT DISTINCT sender, receiver
  FROM pm
  WHERE receiver = :username
     or sender   = :username
");

$result = $query->execute(array("username" => $username));
```

**Notice** the documentation suggests you should use a colon like this → `":username" => $username`. A little known goodie about PDO parameter binding is that the `:` is optional. Youpi!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(":username" => $username)` since you are using placeholders `WHERE receiver = :username` as per the link to the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: ^--« As per example #2 of the manual's link you included http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-, nope. The `:` is optional. Pretty f awesome, right?

Comment: Pretty much! If it's optional, great. I didn't find it in their documentation (*yet*), but I'll take your word for it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for calling it out anyhow. I added a **notice** at the bottom of my post for people with similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I think `DISTINCT` would not work for this. Because `DISTINCT` will return unique combinations of sender and reciever, so ('otuser1', 'otuser2') and ('otuser2', 'otuser1') would be different.

Easiest solution:

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php