# How to select only distinct values for two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE `region_details` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Lets assume I have 10 records as follows

```
id     file_id     region
1      aaa         a
2      bbb         b
3      ccc         a
4      ddd         c
5      abc         d
6      a01         a
7      j05         b
8      005         c
9      a1021       a
10     111j        b
```

I need id and region for distinct region values

```
   id     region
    1     a
    2     b
    4     c
    5     d
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select only unique values from a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571902/mysql-select-only-unique-values-from-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`, use `MIN(id)` to pick each region's first id.

```
select min(id) as id, region
from region_details
group by region
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT min(id),region
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY region
```

Answer (score -1):

The other two answers are rolling up Id into an aggregate function (`min`, or `max` or some other reduce-function), but looking at the data, it may turn out to be the case that what you want are all the unique combinations of id and region, which you can find by using the following:

```
select id, region
from yourtable
group by id, region
```

If you want to get an idea of how/whether/which columns are rolled up, due to the existence of multiple files for a given id/region combination, you might try:

```
select id, region, count(*)
from yourtable
group by id, region
```

Any rows with a `count(*)` value higher than 1 are indications that you've got multiple files scurried away under those particular combinations.