# mySQL "IN" function to Return the list of not found

Tags: mysql

Just wanted to ask if this is possible or a way to determine the strings that is not on my table. for example

select name from table_person where name IN('name1','name2','name3')

- scenario is name1 and name2 is available on my table but what I want to display is name3, since I want to know what are the things I haven't added.

Comment: Are you asking about `NOT IN`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL "NOT IN" query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Comment: So lets call name1, name2 and name3 set B.  Set A is all the data in your table_person.  You want all records in set B where no record exists in set A?

Comment: No, because it still won't display the name3 in there since it is not on my table. What I wanted to achieved is that from the list of my arguments which of those are not present on my table.

Comment: @xQbert, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just playing around with the worst approach (may be).

<sub>Not Recommended</sub>

```
SELECT 
 suppliedArgTable.name 
FROM 
(
 SELECT 'name1' AS name
 UNION 
 SELECT 'name2' 
 UNION 
 SELECT 'name3' 
) AS suppliedArgTable

LEFT JOIN 

table_person TP ON TP.name = suppliedArgTable.name 
WHERE TP.name IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edcbe/2/0

Comment: yep, that's kinda like that, but what if I have 100 arguments to check and 14 of them is  missing from my table.

Comment: I just showed the other way around. But I don't recommend this. Better do this kind of job in application logic.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a way around this.  Your master set of data you want to compare against isn't in the database. So first have to some how get it there... either a union query load it into a table first and then do this.

Comment: I agree. I don't advocate this @xQbert

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` combined with reversing your query is a solution.

With the 'list' `('name1','name2','name3')` in a (temporary) table e.g. `temp_list`
and with the data in `table_person`
the query would be:

```
select name from temp_list 
where name not in (
    select distinct(name) from table_person
)
```

`distinct` removes doubles. (see also [MySQL: Select only unique values from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571902/mysql-select-only-unique-values-from-a-column))

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name_field
FROM   (VALUES('name1'),
              ('name2'),
              ('name3'),
              ('name4'),
              ('name5')) V(name_field)
EXCEPT
SELECT name_field
FROM   name_table
```

You can use a **temporary table** to hold a list of all names and find non-matching names with `EXCEPT`.