# Fetch unique userID from database with a given date

Tags: php, mysql

```
|--------------------------------------
|  luid |  alti   | lati  |   sdate   | 
|--------------------------------------
|  14  |  11.222  | 11.22 |18-10-2016 |
|  14  |  22.333  | 11.22 |18-10-2016 |
|  12  |  32.111  | 11.22 |18-10-2016 |
|  12  |  11.234  | 11.22 |18-10-2016 |
|  13  |  24.555  | 11.22 |18-10-2016 |
|  16  |  16.000  | 11.22 |19-10-2016 |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to fetch the unique **luid** from the table of **18-20-2016**
and the total column also.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Try `DISTINCT`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571902/mysql-select-only-unique-values-from-a-column this can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Column_Name) AS Column_Name FROM Table_Name ORDER BY Column_Name DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY This 
SELECT `luid` from `table` WHERE `sdate`="required date" Group By `luid`