# Unique results from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want parent to be unique from this query:

```
select 
  *, 
  (select state_name 
   from tbl_states 
   where state_id = tbl_cities.parent_id) as parent 
from 
  tbl_cities 
ORDER BY 
  parent
```

I have tried to use :

```
select 
  *, 
  DISTINCT (select state_name 
            from tbl_states 
            where state_id = tbl_cities.parent_id) as parent 
from 
  tbl_cities 
ORDER BY 
  parent
```

but it gives an error.

Comment: what's the error thrown?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT (select state_name from tbl_states where state_id = tbl_cities.parent_i' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL How to Return Unique/Distinct Results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663181/mysql-how-to-return-unique-distinct-results)

Answer (score 0):

The order of terms is incorrect. You want

```
select DISTINCT * ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you should put the DISTINCT inside the sub-select:

```
select * , 
 (select DISTINCT state_name 
  from tbl_states 
  where state_id = tbl_cities.parent_id) as parent 
from tbl_cities ORDER BY parent
```

I don't understand why you would get multiple states, are they really the same state repeated?
If there are different states, then you have a different issue. In that case, the following will work, as far as syntax goes:

```
select * , 
 (select MAX(state_name) 
  from tbl_states 
  where state_id = tbl_cities.parent_id) as parent 
from tbl_cities ORDER BY parent
```

But the semantics could be wrong for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write like this, and get the added benefit of ANSI-compliance.

```
select 
  c.*, parent.state_name
from 
  tbl_cities c
  left join (
    select 
      state_id, state_name 
    from 
      tbl_states 
    group by 
      state_id, state_name
  ) as parent 
  on parent.state_id = c.parent_id
order by 
  parent.state_name;
```